# How do I know which environment variable file is overwriting my `/etc/profile.d/jdk13.sh`?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I'm trying to install java-13 on Ubuntu 18.04 following [this tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-debian/).

I've installed java-11 before which is preventing these commands taking effect

```
  sudo mv jdk-13 /opt/
  sudo tee /etc/profile.d/jdk13.sh <<EOF
  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-13
  export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin
  EOF
  source /etc/profile.d/jdk13.sh
```

`type java` command gives this

```
java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)
```

I guess this is due to some setting in some environment variables config file e.g. $HOME/.profile.

How do I know which file is overwriting my `/etc/profile.d/jdk13.sh`?

---

I also tried this command

```
export PATH=\$JAVA_HOME/bin:\$PATH
```

and got

```
java -version
Command 'java' is available in '/usr/bin/java'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change path for command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885467/how-to-change-path-for-command)

Comment: For the case of java/javac specifically, it may be preferable to use the `update-alternatives` mechanism - either directly, or via `update-java-alternatives`. See for example [Is there a way to update all Java related alternatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141791/is-there-a-way-to-update-all-java-related-alternatives)

Comment: @JJJohn This can help you understand the problem more: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137805/cant-reset-my-java-home-to-new-open-jdk-11-java-installation/1137883#1137883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've "installed java-11 before"… using the same/a similar procedure which includes creating a shell script in `/etc/profile.d`? And is it still installed? Have a look at the output of `type java`–this should tell you whether the binaries like `java` are (still?) found in another directory ("first").
If you want to use different versions in parallel, have a look at `man update-alternatives` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/233192/525098) which explains how to cleanly switch between versions of the same (suite of) program(s). This can include auxiliary scripts which modify PATH, or you could use a script which actually sets the environment variables based on the location of the `java` binary.

Comment: Thank you. `type java` command gives `java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)` what does that mean?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105878/238272 – however, while you explicitly can clear said command cache, the underlying problem should be the fact that your $PATH includes directory `/usr/bin` which contains a binary or link called `java` that always takes precedence. Try using `export PATH=\$JAVA_HOME/bin:\$PATH` above instead.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post. I got `Command 'java' is available in '/usr/bin/java'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.`